# Airflow dag stuck in running state

Tags: airflow

My airflow dag was stuck in the running state. The task were in null state and will not get scheduled. This dag is set to be depends_on_past and the previous dag run failed, however I already set the previous run to success state through UI. But it still not kick of the new run.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the *start_date* parameter, if it's set for a concrete date like run the process weekly starting from today, so then you will have to wait for a week or put *start_date* parameter at today - 7 days. It's rare but for me it worked.

Could you share your DAG code?